# Getting the next AUTO_INCREMENT value of a SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, auto-increment

Using the typical SQLiteDatabase object in Android's API, what can I do to get the next `AUTO_INCREMENT` value of a particular column (ie. `id`) without affecting the value itself. Is there a method for that? Or what query should I execute to get that result. Keep in mind that SQLiteDatabase.query() returns a `Cursor` object, so I'm not too sure how to deal with that directly if I just want to get a value out of it.

Comment: Trying to get this value is a bad design pattern from the get-go. What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're right. The first answer (still below) only works without an AUTOINCREMENT for id. With AUTOINCREMENT, the values are stored in a separate table and used for the increment. Here's an example of finding the value:

```
public void printAutoIncrements(){
    String query = "SELECT * FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE";
    Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            System.out.println("tableName: " +cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
            System.out.println("autoInc: " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("seq")));

        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close(); 

}
```

See: http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

First Answer:

You can query for the max of the _id column, such as:

```
String query = "SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id FROM mytable";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

int id = 0;     
if (cursor.moveToFirst())
{
    do
    {           
        id = cursor.getInt(0);                  
    } while(cursor.moveToNext());           
}
return id;
```

This works for row ids that haven't been specified as "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" (all tables have a row id column).

Comment: The max id of the table may not necessarily be the AUTO_INCREMENT value because what if rows with higher id's were deleted? Getting the max id would not be correct.

Comment: @aha you can obviously use **cursor.getCount()** and increment its value and store it as auto-increment value.......

Comment: @hanry cursor.getCount() will most likely be the wrong approach every time: any time a row has been deleted from the table. For tables without an autoincrement row id, the default row id is incremented from the max.

Comment: before trying to do it we have to check if have any row was inserted to this table, if we don't have return some constant id

Comment: `cursor.moveToFirst()` is false

Comment: didn't manage to get it work, `cursor.moveToFirst()` is always false...

Answer (score 12):

This is the best way to get the last ID on auto increment PRIMARY KEY with SQLITE

`String query = "select seq from sqlite_sequence WHERE name = 'Table_Name'"`

Comment: Excellent! SQLite insert automatically the next cursor value. Best way!!

Answer (score 9):

An important remark about the SQLITE_SEQUENCE table.

The documentation says

> The SQLITE_SEQUENCE table is created and initialized automatically whenever a normal table that contains an AUTOINCREMENT column is created.

So the SQLITE_SEQUENCE table is created, but NOT the row associated with the table that contains the AUTOINCREMENT column. That row is created with the first insert query (with "seq" value of 1).

That means that you must doing at least one insert operation before looking for the next autoincrement value of a specific table. It could be done for example just after the creation of the table, performing an insert and a delete of a dummy row.

Comment: yes we just have to check if we can moveToFirst or getCount before trying to get next increment value

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I use to get the next *AUTOINCREMENT* value for a specific table:

```
/**
 * Query sqlite_sequence table and search for the AUTOINCREMENT value for <code>tableName</code>
 * @param tableName The table name with which the AUTOINCREMENT value is associated.
 *
 * @return The next AUTOINCREMENT value for <code>tableName</code>
 * If an INSERT call was not previously executed on <code>tableName</code>, the value 1 will
 * be returned. Otherwise, the returned value will be the next AUTOINCREMENT.
 */
private long getNextAutoIncrement(String tableName) {
    /*
     * From the docs:
     * SQLite keeps track of the largest ROWID using an internal table named "sqlite_sequence".
     * The sqlite_sequence table is created and initialized automatically
     * whenever a normal table that contains an AUTOINCREMENT column is created.
     */
    String sqliteSequenceTableName = "sqlite_sequence";
    /*
     * Relevant columns to retrieve from <code>sqliteSequenceTableName</code>
     */
    String[] columns = {"seq"};
    String selection = "name=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = { tableName };

    Cursor cursor = mWritableDB.query(sqliteSequenceTableName, 
            columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

    long autoIncrement = 0;

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int indexSeq = cursor.getColumnIndex(columns[0]);
        autoIncrement = cursor.getLong(indexSeq);
    }

    cursor.close();

    return autoIncrement + 1;
}
```

Comment: Just to know, what happens if you insert a record with ID = ´autoIncrement + 1´ and then you insert a record without specifying an ID ? For example : The sequence = 9, you return 10 in this case and insert a record with ID = 10 (specified). Then, you insert a new record without specifying an ID. Does SQLite know that he has to insert 11 for the ID ? Or will he try to insert 10 and result in an error ?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the SQLiteOpenHelper you use, start a transaction. Insert some data and then rollback.

Such a way, you 'll be able to get the next row id, like this:

```
public long nextId() {
    long rowId = -1;

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        // fill values ...

        // insert a valid row into your table
        rowId = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        // NOTE: we don't call  db.setTransactionSuccessful()
        // so as to rollback and cancel the last changes
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
    return rowId;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's work.

```
public static long getNextId(SQLiteDatabase db, String tableName) {
    Cursor c = null;
    long seq = 0;
    try {
        String sql = "select seq from sqlite_sequence where name=?";
        c = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {tableName});
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            seq = c.getLong(0);
        }
    } finally {
        if (c != null) {
            c.close();
        }
    }
    return seq + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cursor.getInt(i);` method
`i` here is index of the id column

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Select * From mSignUp", null);
            String mail = null;
            try {
                while (c.moveToNext()) {
                    mail = c.getString(0);
                    String pas = c.getString(1);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name = " + mail + " Pass = " + pas, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }catch (CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                Log.e("OutOfBound", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            }
            finally {
                c.close();
            }
```